# How can i tell if this repository is using python3 or 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, github

https://github.com/tekno45/dndchar

I forked this repository and i'd like to work on it at work. Is there a way to tell if it's written in 3 or 2?

Comment: `print` is a statement not a function, it's Python 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's written in Python 2.

The biggest hint is that `print` is a statement there, not a function.